# Canoe :- How to use masking of bits in CAPL scripting

Tags: capl, canoe

I wanted to mask my 6bits signal to pass value 20 degree Celsius

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
int firstvalue = 0xFF;
int secondValue = 0x55;
int result = 0;

result = firstvalue & 0xAA;
write("0xFF & 0xAA = %X", result);

result = secondValue & 0xAA;
write("0x55 & 0xAA %X", result);

result = secondValue & 0x01;
write("0x55 & 0x01 %X", result);

result = secondValue & 0;
write("0x55 & 0 %X", result);

result = firstvalue & 0x01;
write("0xFF & 0x01 %X", result);
```